# Is firebase-jobdispatcher removed from Android 12?

Tags: android, android-12, firebase-job-dispatcher

I tired to migrate my form `Android 11` to `Android 12`. Then I ended up with following run time error,

> Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Then I have gone through multiple SO and github threads and tried couple of solutions, But nothing worked. Finally I realised the error is because of `firebase-jobdispatcher`. Then I commented the following line in app/build.gradle,

```
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
```

And all the code related to `firebase-jobdispatcher`. Then there is no error.

Can I assume that `firebase-jobdispatcher` is removed from `Android 12`?

or

Is there anyway to make `firebase-jobdispatcher` work in `Android 12`?

Comment: Also curious about Android 13, if someone knows